# Vue store a variable on one page and call on another

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

**How can I pass value from config.js file to Geturl.vue ?**

config.js file contains

```
 var myUrl = "http://localhost:7070/#/";
```

My View (Geturl.vue)

```
<div id="app>>
 <p>{{loadNewUrl}}</p>
</div>
```

Script for Geturl.vue

```
<script>

  import config from '/config.js';

  export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },

  data(){
    return{
      loadNewUrl: myUrl,  /** how to get myUrl value from config.js file **/
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to export the variable in config.js first, then import that variable in your `Geturl.vue`:

**config.js**

`export var myUrl = "http://localhost:7070/#/";`

**Script for Geturl.vue**

```
<script>

  import { myUrl } from '/config.js';

  export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  },

  data(){
    return{
      loadNewUrl: myUrl,  /** how to get myUrl value from config.js file **/
    }
  }
</script>
```

More:

- https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

The variables in the **JS** file are not accessible from other files - `export` makes them "public"